# Problem with overwriting diagram files using feynmf

Tags: packages, miktex, windows

I've just installed `feynmf` package and tried working with a standard example. I'm working with MikTeX 2.9 on Windows. The compilation worked fine and I got the diagram in the PDF, but when changing the code nothing happens. It seems as if there is some problem with the rights concerning overwriting the already created diagram files.

There was another question similar to this one and the answer was simply "rerun mf after a change in a diagram".

I have already tried but I still got the same problem. I can't overwrite the already created diagram and I always get the same diagram.

The way I rerun mf is:

```
mf "\mode=localfont; input diag1"
```

where (of course) "diag1" is the fmffile name in .tex source.

MWE:

```
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{fmffile}{diag1}
   \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30)
      \fmfleftn{i}{2}
      ...
   \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suggest you `feynmp` instead of `feynmf`; using Metapost is more friendly than using Metafont. The syntax is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you. I loaded the feynmp package but now my compiler does not recognize the graphics extension.                                 It finds an error in \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30) ...

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: \usepackage{feynmp} ...                                               \begin{document}                                                    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}                                        \begin{fmffile}{diag1}                                              \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30)                                          \fmfleftn{i}{2} ...                                               \end{fmfgraph*}                                                   \end{fmffile} ...                                                    I find LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1

Comment: and the error is at the line where I wrote \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30)

Comment: I was compiling with pdflatex...this seems to be the problem. Now I have tried with the following: 1. latex ... 2. mpost ... 3. latex ... 4. dvips ... 5. conversion from ps to pdf.           It seems to work and overwrite correctly the created diagram. I don't know why! But thank you for having suggested to use Metapost.

Comment: You might also try `feynmp-auto` that (at least on TeX Live, couldn't test on MiKTeX) even avoids the need to run Metapost.